# Best practices for distributed development in PHP

Tags: php, controls, version, distributed

Let's say there are 5 developers who are working on a web application in PHP. What tools do you use so development is done efficiently. Because each developer will be working on its own module so how do they manage it? For e.g. if you are developing for .Net then you have Visual Studio for this purpose and other tools.
I know I can use SVN or GIT for version control but how will we collect code from developers? I mean will developer email some person responsible for repository who will then merge their code or is there an IDE or some tool available that will do this automatically?

I hope I made myself clear.

Thanks

Comment: SVN is good option. But still I will take daily backups

Answer (score 3):

All programmers use `svn` or `git` from a single host server visible to all developers.  You don't collect code—each developer checks in their changes when they are confident they are an improvement to the body of work.

Answer (score 1):

My only experience has been with git.  With the company that I work for we have a development domain where each worker has their own development environment....

bob-smith.testdomain.com
jane-doe.testdomain.com
john-doe.testdomain.com
etc., etc.

Each developer has a git repository in their document root and ssh access to the server where they can checkout different branches into their environment.

We use [lighthouse](http://lighthouseapp.com/) to track bugs and new features that we like incorporated into our application.  When a ticket is created in lighthouse a unique number is assigned to the ticket.  When a team member starts a new project we create a new branch off of master.

Lets say that the ticket is #501 and the title may be Add Widget.  We would name our branch t501-add-widget.  We can update the status of our branch in lighthouse and visualize any work done in our repository on github.

Once we're ready for a release we go into lighthouse and look for all tickets that have been marked ready to merge.  These branches are merged into our master branch and then staged to our test environment, and finally our alpha environment before finally being deployed live.  The combo of git, github, and lighthouse app have been great for us.  I really can't imagine doing it any other way right now.